# Checkbox doesn't stay selected after saving

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a problem. I've got this custom form built. At the top I have 3 options to select. Once the checkbox is selected then text shows up below. I managed to implement it so that's great. I also have radio selection and text.

My problem is that after clicking save form everything stays selected apart from the checkbox. I have 0 idea how to fix it. Maybe someone knows?

I have no idea why it's not working.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <p id="mt-error">Please select one of the treatments</p>
  <p>
    <b>Botox®/ Azzalure ®/Bocouture®/Alluzience® Injections</b><input type="checkbox" id="botox_checkbox" name="botox_checkbox" class="mt-checkbox" />
  </p>
</div>
<div id="botox_terms">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="liststyle">
      <li>
        I hereby give my consent to the aesthetic medical treatment known as Botulinum Toxin injections. All aspects of this treatment and the potential risks and complications have been fully explained to me, and I have had the opportunity to ask questions about
        the procedure including the limitations. All information has been given to me in clear and simple language. Not only have all questions been answered to my complete satisfaction but I also fully understand all the answers that have been given
        to me, and the practitioner has clarified all doubts that I have raised to my practitioner. I have had the opportunity to discuss alternative forms of treatment to obtain the results I desire, and I am satisfied that injection with Botulinum Toxin
        is the most suitable treatment in my particular case.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name^="date"]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-100:+0',
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    resizeSignatures();
  });

  createSignature('guest-signature', {
    required: true,
  });

  createSignature('medical-signature', {
    required: true,
  });

  $('input[name^="date"]').each(function() {
    var dateFormat = new Date($(this).val());
    var month =
      parseInt(dateFormat.getMonth()) < 9 ?
      '0' + (dateFormat.getMonth() + 1) :
      dateFormat.getMonth() + 1;
    var newDate = dateFormat.getDate() + '/' + month + '/' + dateFormat.getFullYear();
    if (newDate.length > 0 && newDate.indexOf('NaN') < 0) {
      $(this).val(newDate);
    }
  });

  var now = new Date();
  var day = ('0' + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var month = ('0' + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var today = day + '/' + month + '/' + now.getFullYear();

  $('#dateGuestsignature').val(today);

  var myaddress = $('#addresshid').val();
  $('#Address').val(myaddress);

  $('#form').focusout(function(e) {
    var reqAttr = $(e.target).attr('required');
    errorMessage(e, reqAttr);
  });

  $('input[name^="date"]').change(function(e) {
    var reqAttr = $(e.target).attr('required');
    errorMessage(e, reqAttr);
  });

  $('#form').focusout(function(e) {
    var reqAttr = $(e.target).attr('required');
    errorMessage(e, reqAttr);
  });
});

$('#botox_checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#botox_terms').show();
  } else {
    $('#botox_terms').hide();
  }
});

$('#inj1_checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#inj1_terms').show();
  } else {
    $('#inj1_terms').hide();
  }
});

$('#inj2_checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#inj2_terms').show();
  } else {
    $('#inj2_terms').hide();
  }
});

$("#form").on('submit', function(event) {
  let checked = false;

  const checkboxes = $(".mt-checkbox");
  for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      checked = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!checked) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#mt-error").show();
    window.location.href = "#mt-error";
  } else {
    $("#mt-error").hide();
  }
});
// Function to save checkbox states to localStorage
function saveCheckboxState(checkboxId, checked) {
  localStorage.setItem(checkboxId, checked);
}

// Function to retrieve checkbox states from localStorage
function getCheckboxState(checkboxId) {
  return localStorage.getItem(checkboxId) === 'true';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialize checkbox states on page load
  $('#botox_checkbox').prop('checked', getCheckboxState('botox_checkbox'));
  $('#inj1_checkbox').prop('checked', getCheckboxState('inj1_checkbox'));
  $('#inj2_checkbox').prop('checked', getCheckboxState('inj2_checkbox'));

  // Update and save checkbox states when they change
  $('#botox_checkbox, #inj1_checkbox, #inj2_checkbox').change(function() {
    saveCheckboxState(this.id, this.checked);
  });
});
```

Comment: The checkbox state seems to be saved absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/dnv7es0L/. Your issue seems to be that you're not showing/hiding the `#botox_tems` element if the box is checked on page load.

Comment: Also note for future reference, it's a much better idea to ***only*** include the relevant parts of your code when making a question. There's a lot of code in there that's referencing missing libraries/functions which are not relevant to the issue. The easier ***you*** make it for someone to be able to understand, run and debug your code, the better and more accurate the answers you get will be

Comment: can you edit in a stack snippet, such that we can see the problem? also, at least try and put in some effort and do some debugging to figure out the root of the problem.